# Firefox change download folder monthly via python script

Tags: python, firefox, automation

I would like to change monthly the download directory of **Firefox** browser, so my downloaded files get arranged in folders chronologically.

This month is January, 2017, so I would like that all my downloads get into a folder named "Jan_17".

Next month, on the first day I would like the folder to be changed ***automatically and programmatically*** via a **python** script into something like "Feb_17".

I quickly searched in **about:config** and thought a possible solution could go with this but I can't go further.

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: nothing particular, searched in about:config for keyword 'download' and found a record containing my current download dir

Comment: but I can't imagine a way to access that field and change it via python